# С чего начать разработку под десктопные ОС (в частности, Windows, Qt)?

Tags: c++, qt

На днях появилась необходимость в написании довольно продвинутого ПО для десктопных систем (сперва Windows, а после, возможно, все остальное).

Среди всех доступных фреймворков больше всего привлекает `Qt`: кроссплатформенность, приемлемые требование к ресурсам и большое сообщество. В `C++` ориентируюсь не слишком свободно, поэтому сейчас приходится изучать.

В проекте нужен современный `GUI`, высокий уровень контроля и достойная производительность, поэтому `QML`, скорее всего, не подойдет.

При написании решил ориентироваться на исходный код `Telegram`. Однако проблема в том, что разобраться во всем этом изобилии кода весьма непросто: "Почему тут так?", "Зачем это используют?", "Что делает этот участок?" и прочее.

Следовательно, вопрос довольно банальный: как начать писать? С чего стоит начинать? Подходящей продвинутой литературы не нашел (банальный пересказ документации, боюсь, не сильно поможет).

Comment: вы сделали хороший выбор, читайте документацию.

Comment: "В проекте нужен современный GUI, высокий уровень контроля и достойная производительность, поэтому QML, скорее всего, не подойдет." - почему? :)

Comment: "В C++ ориентируюсь не слишком свободно, поэтому сейчас приходится изучать." - у вас трудности с c++ или вы в принципе не имеете опыта разработки подобного рода приложений?

Comment: а ведь есть ещё electron, react-native, flutter, питоновские фреймворки...

Comment: QML много чего делает у себя под капотом, к чему, кажется, разработчик попросту не имеет доступа. И он вряд ли быстрее виджетов. Но в современный интерфейс, конечно, может, да.

Comment: В первую очередь из-за отсутствия опыта (до C++ еще не дошло, по сути). До этого писал немного под Android.

Comment: В проекте понадобятся низкоуровневые C/C++ библиотеки (`ffmpeg`, например), поэтому такие штуки вряд ли пригодны.

Comment: nodejs умеет в низкоуровневые библиотеки. в ffmpeg тем более

Comment: "с чего начать" с подготовки архитектуры крупными блоками исходя из бизнес-требований. дальше детализировать и укладывать архитектуру в средства фреймворка